# checking age in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm a newbie to Mysql, I need help to find horses that are more than 10 years old from horse table, which consists columns as 'Born' & 'Died' in years only, i.e. for e.g. Born (1986) Died (1998).

Comment: I guess you mean horses that reached and passed the age of 10. Not only the alive ones. It would help if ypu posted the table structure (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`). Read this, too: **[Help us help you : keys to getting good answers](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)**

Comment: Simple query. I think this belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Migrating this to [so] as it's too simple for needing a DBA, and instead just needs basic SQL programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

Thoroughbred horses are deemed to have been born on January 1 of their birth year. So you just need simple subtraction to get the right answer.

```
select horse_name
from horses
where born < (year(current_date) - 10)
  and died is null;
```

Change the operator from "<" to "<=" if you really meant to find horses 10 years or older.